# Map a colorbar based on plot instead of imshow

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

I'm trying to get a colorbar for the following minimal example of my code.

```
g1 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1)
f, ((ax0)) = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax0 = subplot(g1[0])

cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('viridis')

for i in linspace(0,1,11):
    x = [-1,0,1]
    y = [i,i,i]
    rgba = cmap(i)
    im = ax0.plot(x,y,color=rgba)

f.colorbar(im)
```

I also tried `f.colorbar(cmap)`

Probably pretty obvious, but I get errors such as

```
'ListedColormap' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'
```

In reality, the value defining i is more complex, but I think this should do the trick. My data is plotted with plot and not with imshow (for which I know how to make the colormap).

Comment: I found a way. Will update it soon.

Comment: With a bit of delay, here is what I found on friday after posting the initial question. `Z = [[0,0],[0,0]]
levels = linspace(-1.5,5.5,11) #range(-1.4433333,5.5133333+s,step)
CS3 = plt.contourf(Z, levels, cmap=mymap)
plt.clf()` is what I used to define my scalarmappable, based on another post I found on SO. But the offered solutions here seem more appriopriate and solve the problem more directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers so far seem overly complicated. `fig.colorbar()` expects a `ScalarMappable` as its first argument. Often `ScalarMappable`s are produced by `imshow` or `contour`plots and are readily avaible.

In this case you would need to define your custom `ScalarMappable` to provide to the colorbar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis')

for i in np.linspace(0,1,11):
    x = [-1,0,1]
    y = [i,i,i]
    rgba = cmap(i)
    im = ax.plot(x,y,color=rgba)

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap)
sm.set_array([])
fig.colorbar(sm)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How do you manage to display the figure at half of the page width? Mine is displayed so unnecessarily big ...

Comment: Inside the SO post.

Comment: Here I run the matplotlib code, shrink the appearing window, make a screenshot, copy the screenshot into IrfanView, select the region of interest, hit Strg+C, and paste it into the SO post. Another option would be to already create a smaller figure from the code `plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 3,3`, and use that one. Last option: Instead of showing the picture with `![][1]` syntax, use html `<img src="https://url.to.pic/pic.png" width="350">` in the SO post.

Comment: Thank you, the last one was what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't understand how this works... how does the loop "know" that there are only 10 lines to plot and to map the first one to the lowest (purple) color and the last one to the highest (yellow)? I tried it out with 20, 30, etc. plots and the mapping remains in tact: first line purple, last line yellow.... very unintuitive  behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an `Image` or `ContourSet` when you call `colorbar` on a `Figure`.
You can make an image of the data points by calling `plt.imshow` with the data. You can start with this:

```
data = []
for i in np.linspace(0,1,11):
    x = [-1,0,1]
    y = [i,i,i]
    rgba = cmap(i)
    ax0.plot(x,y,color=rgba)
    data.append([x, y])

image = plt.imshow(data)

figure.colorbar(image)

plt.show()
```

Reference:

- https://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar

Answer (score 1):

[Oluwafemi Sule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5189811/oluwafemi-sule)'s solution almost works, but it plots the matrix into the same figure as the lines. Here a solution that opens a second figure, does the `imshow` call on that second figure, uses the result to draw the `colorbar` in the first figure, and then closes the second figure before calling `plt.show()`:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np

cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('viridis')

g1 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1)
f0, ((ax0)) = plt.subplots(1, 1)
f1, ((ax1)) = plt.subplots(1, 1)

for i in np.linspace(0,1,11):
    x = [-1,0,1]
    y = [i,i,i]
    rgba = cmap(i)
    ax0.plot(x,y,color=rgba)

data = np.linspace(0,1,100).reshape((10,10))
image = ax1.imshow(data)
f0.colorbar(image)
plt.close(f1)

plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]