# Difficulty to plot a graph showing the Current Speed and Direction VS Depth in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have difficulty to  plot a graph showing the Current Speed and Direction VS Depth in python  I have tried following code but all arrows are coming on single color and if change the value of speed the size of arrow is too big, I do not want to show any thing on x axis but in bellow code it is required to set xlim  in bellow example speed and direction are converted in u and v using

```
u=ws*cos(wd)

v=ws*sin(wd)


data=[(0, 1.95, -0.8159606717671093, 2.2197413061368696), (0, 2.95, -0.3582079405727933, 1.2392687647603318), (0, 3.95, -0.31686646083755926, 1.291702615154231), (0, 4.95, -0.29746052030193276, 1.2860471371072304), (0, 5.95, -0.26344777968183913, 1.262812443469223), (0, 6.95, -0.23878868113642596, 1.2065985105912929), (0, 7.95, -0.25428152412858535, 1.1727492939613495), (0, 8.95, -0.23806795164869818, 1.1148648574593214), (0, 9.95, -0.17646920235662847, 1.1060102262726217), (0, 10.95, -0.18770370727477204, 1.0838668360436658), (0, 11.95, -0.17964112037348914, 1.054812337750634), (0, 12.95, -0.16791299403578752, 1.0060841050498401)]
data = np.array(data, dtype=[('x', np.float32), ('y', np.float32), ('u',   np.float32), ('v', np.float32)])

plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
colors = np.arctan2(data['u'], data['v'])
norm = Normalize()
norm.autoscale(colors)
colormap = plt.colormaps()
colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(data)))
cs = [colors[i//len(data['x'])] for i in range(len(data)*len(data['x']))]

ax.quiver(data['x'], data['y'], data['u'], data['v'], angles='uv',     scale_units='xy', scale=1,color=cs,pivot='mid')
ax.set_xlim([-1, 10])
plt.xticks(rotation=0)


 plt.draw()
 plt.show()
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) What is the criteria you want your arrows colour-coded after? (2) In what sense are the arrows 'too long' -- it looks fine for me. Do you mean that they overlap?

Comment: colour should be based on speed and If I increase the the speed the arrow size will increased I am unable to sort out this plz help me .    I want arrow should indicate the direction and colour should indicate the speed and I want legend also  and  now I hope   it is clear to you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want all speed vectors to indicate the current direction of motion but to be of the same length. To achieve this, you have to normalise your speed vectors before passing them to `quiver`. For the colour coding of the vectors (to indicate the absolute speed value) you had a small problem with the syntax. See the code below. I also added code to add a `colorbar` to the plot (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44328461/2454357)).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

data=[(0, 1.95, -0.8159606717671093, 2.2197413061368696), (0, 2.95, -0.3582079405727933, 1.2392687647603318), (0, 3.95, -0.31686646083755926, 1.291702615154231), (0, 4.95, -0.29746052030193276, 1.2860471371072304), (0, 5.95, -0.26344777968183913, 1.262812443469223), (0, 6.95, -0.23878868113642596, 1.2065985105912929), (0, 7.95, -0.25428152412858535, 1.1727492939613495), (0, 8.95, -0.23806795164869818, 1.1148648574593214), (0, 9.95, -0.17646920235662847, 1.1060102262726217), (0, 10.95, -0.18770370727477204, 1.0838668360436658), (0, 11.95, -0.17964112037348914, 1.054812337750634), (0, 12.95, -0.16791299403578752, 1.0060841050498401)]
data = np.array(data, dtype=[('x', np.float32), ('y', np.float32), ('u',   np.float32), ('v', np.float32)])


fig,ax = plt.subplots()

##computing absolute speed value and color scale
##ajust min_speed and max_speed as needed
speed = np.sqrt(data['u']**2+data['v']**2)
min_speed = np.min(speed)
max_speed = np.max(speed)
scale = (speed-min_speed)/(max_speed-min_speed)

##normalizing the speed components:
##adjust the vector length with fac
fac = 1.0
u_norm = fac*data['u']/speed
v_norm = fac*data['v']/speed

##the colormap:
cmap = cm.get_cmap('rainbow')
cs = cmap(scale)

##the arrows
ax.quiver(data['x'], data['y'], u_norm, v_norm, angles='uv',     scale_units='xy', scale=1,color=cs,pivot='mid')
ax.set_xlim([-1, 10])

##the colorbar (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44328461/2454357):
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap)
sm.set_array(np.linspace(min_speed,max_speed,10))
fig.colorbar(sm)
plt.xticks(rotation=0)

plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result of the code sample]

Hope this helps.